# C# MVC Model is empty when trying to load Bootstrap panels dynamically

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I am totally new to MVC so if I have omitted what you need or don't seem to know what I am doing, you are right. I don't.

Problem: I am trying to display bootstrap panels from data in the database.  The data is in the table,
but the Model is NULL and has no data when I get to the @for statement in the view.
I have tried passing the data as iEnumerable<> and List<>.  I can compile this with List<> but the Model is empty.
How/where do I fill the Model with data?

Here is my controller code:

```
public IActionResult Index(List<HomePanelDisplay> hpd)
    {
        return View(hpd);
    }
```

Here is the model:

```
public class HomePanelDisplay
{
    [Key]
    public long HDPID { get; set; }
    public string PanelHeader { get; set; }
    public string PanelBody { get; set; }
    public string PanelFooter { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ActiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? InActiveDate { get; set; }
    public string PhotoImage { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<HomePanelDisplay> Panels { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the View code with multiple attempts commented out:

```
@model List<GardenForager.Models.HomePanelDisplay>
<div id="panelCollection">
<div class="row">
    @for (var i=0; i<Model.Count; i++ )
    //@foreach (var item in Model)
    //@for (int i = 0; i < @rows; i++)
    {
        @for (int j = 0; j < @cols; j++)
        {
            if (panelCount <= totalCount)
            {
                //The panelID is the panelCount and PanelID so this can be set here.
                panelID = panelCount.ToString();

                // <p>Panel is @panelID</p>

                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <div class='panel panel-success' data-sid="@i.HDPID" data- 
                                sname="@item.PanelHeader" style="display: inline-block">
                        <div class='panel-heading text-center'>
                            <b>@item.PanelHeader</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body m200">
                            @item.PanelBody
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                            @item.PanelFooter
                        </div>
                    </div>




                </div>
                panelCount = panelCount + 1;
               }
           }

        }
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where do you set the list? because I don't see it. When you go to the view you should declare the data in List<HomePanelDisplay> hpd before go to the index view.